# label value change not immediatly on jquery click

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have a toggle button and there is a label where i want to show the value of the toggle button .  The problem i  am facing is that the label value is not showing the toggle buttons latest value, but the previous value 
[image: Expected No in place of Yes]

> Expected **No** instead of **Yes**

[image]

> Expected Empty insted of **No**

following is  my jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnToggleA3").click(function() {
   
    var textone = ($("#btnToggleA3").val());
    $('#btnToggleB1Analyst').text(textone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<telerik:RadToggleButton ID="btnToggleA3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Font-Size="14px" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <ToggleStates>
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text=" " CssClass="notChecked" />
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="Yes" />
    <telerik:ButtonToggleState Text="No" />
  </ToggleStates>
</telerik:RadToggleButton>

<label id="btnToggleB1Analyst" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        $('#mylabel').text($(this).text());
      });
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label id="mylabel">Temp First Value</label>

    </br>
    </br>
    <button id="mybutton">Hello</button>
```

here is the snippet attached

Comment: The value is not changing

Comment: check the answer again, snippet attached